# Ember.js - Updating a model via Websocket Stream

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to keep my market model updated via the websocket stream.

I have a platform model that has many markets.

When the user first requests the model, it is retrieved from the backend database. I then want to update with the websocket data.

How do I update different values in the model? I can't figure out how to filter the hasmany relationship by market name then set the values. Maybe there's an easier way to go about it that I'm not seeing.

Comment: `store.push` is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple - just make sure you have these things setup:

- you'll want your websocket to send json data to ember, using the same format of json (json:ap for example)
- when you establish your websocket connection on the ember side of things, you'll want an event handler for handling received messages.
- that event handler will use `store.pushPayload` to add/update the model in the store (which means your websocket code needs access to the store).

an example:

```
// some controller.js
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { action } from 'ember-decorators/object';

import myAwesomeWebSocketStuff from 'lib/websocket';


export default class extends Controller {
  init() {
    const socket = myAwesomeWebSocketStuff(this.store);

    this.set('socket', socket');
  }

  willDestroy() {
    this.get('socket').disconnect();
  }      
}
```

and then in `lib/websocket.js`

```
import SomeWebSocketLibrary from 'some-library';

export default function(store) {
  const socket = new SomeWebSocketLibrary(url);

  socket.connect();
  socket.on('receive', data => store.pushPayload(data));

  return socket;
}
```

Comment: I figured it out just as you wrote. Unfortunately I have a rails backend which the model is initialized from then ember keeps things updated with the websocket. I had to modify the websocket output to match the rails API JSON format. This works fine. Then I thought it would be better to keep the rails backend also updated with the websocket, so I'd have to go with ActionCable to keep things simple. I will try to use Ember-Cable with a redis server linking everything together.

Comment: The backend shouldn't matter a whole lot, you can format things however you want :-)

Comment: If you use rails on server then I recommend https://github.com/discourse/message_bus as it does all you expect from websockets and more.